# Component dont call on init with fontawesome

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-universal

Im using the starter demo from angular-universal.
This template has two routes on two buttons, /home and /about.
In this two pages Im requesting different data from an api.
The problem is when I clicked the other button ( /about) the constructor of my component request the data, but dont initialize the component. So i cant see the data on the web.
But if I do perform double click on the button, on init will be called and the data appears.

What im doing bad? Sorry for my english! 
Thanks

Edit: Solved, the problem is fixed if I delete from the index.html this line:

```
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/98c10c6.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. The solution is to not include the .js from an external source.

To still use Font Awesome u need to download the files and put them in your public folder, and reference to those files in index.html. Then it will work properly.